# Can I use the excel transaction file as a Fact table in my data warehouse design

Tags: sql

I have an excel transaction table for a clinick , my source for developing a data warehouse. I have built dimensions that hold a unique key sk and the attributes catagorier t ex Visit dimension that has all the visit types column for patients  and operations codes column in the operation dimentions and so on .
Can I just use the transaction table as a fact table and go direct and built the cube. Or I run ssis lookup package to build the fact table that look up all the dimentions surrogate keys.
Call on the picture of the file [transaction snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1Ak.png)

Can you please tell me what I can do to create a cube out of this data
and which method I can use to build the fact 
There are 12 dimension I need to left up

Comment: I wouldn't.  I would use it as source data and write an ETL script to validate the data and load database tables.

Comment: It all depends on how stable the Excel is. Does it change frequently, seldom or never?